# Error on previwe in ireport on netbeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

I am developing project on net-beans and I have successfully install the ireport plugin for netbeans. After that I have create simple report on ireport but when I try to preview it gave following error.

```
Compiling to file... C:\Users\Public\Documents\Nirmal\Project_Final_Nangi\Project_Final_Nangi\80%of Project\Copy of nadee_Final\src\project\report1.jasper
Error compiling the report java source!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ExtendedJRJdtCompiler
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:501)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1424)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1968)
```

Can someone explain how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the IREPORT designer installed as well? Sometimes there is a version problem withe the DTD of the XML schema.

I would recommend compiling the report templates within IREPORT desinger just to make sure they DO compile as a proper XML format.